# Fixed address on DHCP server isn't working

Tags: networking, server, dhcp, client, dhcpd

I'm running Ubuntu 20.04 as a DHCP server and I tried to assign a fixed address to a client which is another Ubuntu os on a Virtual box, and both of them are in the same internal network, but, it takes only an address from the range I specified, so here's my configuration:

**my /etc/netplan/01-network-manager-all.yaml**

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
  ethernets:
   enp0s3:
    addresses: [10.20.30.2/24]
    nameservers:
     addresses: ["192.168.1.1", "192.168.1.2"]
```

**my /etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf**

```
option domain-name "marmarbre.local";
option domain-name-servers 192.168.1.1, 192.168.1.2;
option ntp-servers 10.20.30.202;
option netbios-name-servers 10.20.30.201;
option nis-domain "marmarbre.ma";
option nis-servers 10.20.30.200;
option routers 10.20.30.1;
option broadcast-address 10.20.30.255;

default-lease-time 86400;
max-lease-time 259200;

subnet 10.20.30.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
  range 10.20.30.50 10.20.30.59;
  range 10.20.30.71 10.20.30.150;
}

host client {
  hardware ethernet 08:00:27:7f:25:60;
  fixed-address 10.20.30.70;
}
```

Finally, this's the only configuration I did on the client and yeah I already changed its hostname to client
**/etc/netplan/01-network-manager-all.yaml**

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `/etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf` file, move your fixed, MAC based, assignment list to **before** the generic dynamic pool declaration. If your client has an old, even expired, lease from the pool it will never get to the MAC based area unless it is declared first.

Note even though things might work properly, you still might get undesirable entries in your log files, which can be corrected by deleting the stale entries in your `/var/lib/dhcp/dhcpd.leases` file and its backup `/var/lib/dhcp/dhcpd.leases~`.