# DHCP server - can I force address reassignment?

Tags: networking, server, dhcp

Ubuntu 18.04.  DHCP server with static assignments.  When a new device comes online, it gets a dynamic assignment.  I take the info, and create a static assignment for that HW address.  I delete the dynamic lease, expecting the static assignment to take over.  But the server continues to ack the device request for its old address.  How do I force it to assign the new static address?  I have tried "arp -d ipaddress" and it just reassigns it again.  I turn the DHCP server off, delete the arp, turn server back on, and immediately see

```
Apr 14 07:25:18 servername dhcpd[1891]: DHCPACK on 10.1.1.192 to 9c:8e:cd:25:ec:c4 (AMC039BE_0FA4B6) via enp2s0
Apr 14 07:25:18 servername dhcpd[1891]: DHCPREQUEST for 10.1.1.192 from 9c:8e:cd:25:ec:c4 via enp2s0
```

and the device is back online again with the wrong IP.  I know I can force power off the device, but these devices are 30 miles away!

Comment: Why do you have a need to change a dynamic DHCP address to a static address? That's the whole point of dynamic addresses... no worries, no pain. I only assign static addresses to systemic hardware devices (in the range of .2 to .99), like routers, extenders, switches, printers, etc, and let dynamic addresses above .100 go to client devices.

Comment: Declare your MAC based assigned addresses first, then your dynamic pool. You might still get a duplicate warning, but your devices should get the desired address. You can also stop your DHCP server, delete both the leases file (`/var/lib/dhcp/dhcpd.leases`) and its backup (`/var/lib/dhcp/dhcpd.leases~`) and start your DHCP server again. See also [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1332797/fixed-address-on-dhcp-server-isnt-working/1332948#1332948).